# Using functions with variables in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, function

I had an assessment for my programming class about calculating insurance using functions. This is the code I was trying to get work but unfortunately I failed:

```
import time

def main():  
        print('Welcome to "Insurance Calculator" ')
        type_I, type_II, type_III = inputs()
        calculationAndDisplay()
        validation()
        time.sleep(3)       

def inputs():
    try:
        type_I = int(input("How many  Type I policies were sold? "))
        type_II = int(input("How many  Type II policies were sold? "))
        type_III = int(input("How many  Type III policies were sold? ")) 
        return type_I, type_II, type_III
    except ValueError:
        print("Inputs must be an integer, please start again")
        inputs()


def calculationAndDisplay():
    type_I *= (500/1.1)
    type_II *= (650/1.1)
    type_III *= (800/1.1)
    print("The amount of annual earned for type_I is: $", type_I)
    print("The amount of annual earned for type_I is: $", type_II)
    print("The amount of annual earned for type_I is: $", type_III)

def validation():
    cont = input("Do you wish to repeat for another year? [Y/N]: ")
    if cont == 'Y' or cont == 'y':
        main()
    elif cont == 'N' or cont == 'n':
        print('Thank You! ------ See You Again!')    
    else:
        print("I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your command.")
        validation()

main()
```

I eventually got it to work by cramming all of the input, calculation, and display into one function. I just want to know how I could have made it work the way intended..

Edit: The program is meant to get the user to input the number of policy's sold and display a before tax total. When I enter a few number inputs it gives me the following error

```
Welcome to "Insurance Calculator" 
How many  Type I policies were sold? 3
How many  Type II policies were sold? 3
How many  Type III policies were sold? 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crazy\Desktop\assessment 2.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\crazy\Desktop\assessment 2.py", line 5, in main
    type_I, type_II, type_III = inputs()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Edit: I moved the return line to the suggested line and now it is giving me an unbound variable error:

```
Welcome to "Insurance Calculator" 
How many  Type I policies were sold? 5
How many  Type II policies were sold? 5
How many  Type III policies were sold? 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crazy\Desktop\assessment 2.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\crazy\Desktop\assessment 2.py", line 6, in main
    calculationAndDisplay()
  File "C:\Users\crazy\Desktop\assessment 2.py", line 22, in 
calculationAndDisplay
    type_I *= (500/1.1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'type_I' referenced before 
assignment
```

Comment: You have to tell us first _how_ it is intended to work and _how_ does it actually work, including all appropriate error messages, if any.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you save the values in variables which only exist inside the `main` method but not in the global scope:

```
type_I, type_II, type_III = inputs()
calculationAndDisplay()
```

Doing this, the `calculationAndDisplay()` method do not know the values. You can solve this, by adding parameters to this functions, like this:

```
def calculationAndDisplay(type_I, type_II, type_III):
    #your code
```

Edit: You code is working without any problem when you perform all calculations in the same method, as now all variables are created inside the same scope. If you use methods, you either have to use function arguments/parameters (the better solution) or use `global` variables (bad solution, as it undermines the concept of the functions).

In the case, that you later on want to use the modified values of `type_I` etc. after calling `calculationAndDisplay()` again, you have to return the modified values in this function, so that you and up with this code:

```
def calculationAndDisplay(type_I, type_II, type_III):
    #your code

    return type_I, type_II, type_III
```

Comment: Your solution works if the function `calculationAndDisplay` is called only once because the original values of the parameters are not updated.

Comment: @DYZ Yes, but this is the intended case, isn't it?

Comment: I do not know. Only the OP knows.

Answer (score 0):

That error which you have mentioned is due to the indentation of the return statement in inputs(). That return statement should be inside **inputs** function(Because in your case inputs() is not returning type_I,type_II,type_II). Also arguments should be passed to calculationAndDisplay(type_I,type_II,type_III).